# Can I rebind Ctrl-C to do the same as ESC in readline?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, readline

I have started using vi mode in bash (`set -o vi`), and my laptop has no escape key (stupid touch bar…) so its annoying to leave insert mode on the command line. This got me thinking that in Vim, I remapped Ctrl-C to the same functionality as the escape key.

Now since Ctrl-C has a very important use in the shell usually, mapping that key combo to Esc may not be a great idea, but out of curiosity:

**Is it possible to map `Ctrl-C` or `Ctrl-$something` to perform the same as the Escape key in readline?**

Comment: `Ctrl-C` is handled by the terminal driver before reaching bash or readline. readline doesn't turn off the `isig` tty setting. But why not just use `Ctrl-[` instead of `Escape` (that's what I do on my old QWERTY phone)

Comment: Have you considered CapsLock? It's a large key right on the home row and its nominal function isn't particularly useful.....

Comment: So far I haven't found an easily digestible resource on the syntax of readline settings. How would rebinding Caps lock look like?

Comment: @mattdm You cannot rebind the `CapsLock` in readline, since `CapsLock` isn't sending any character sequence that could be bound or rebound. And how that could be done in a terminal emulator, linux vt or X11 should be a different Q.

Comment: That's true -- I'd recommend doing it at the terminal or input system level, not as a readline binding.

Answer (score 1):

For the `Ctrl-$something` part, you can use `Ctrl-[` instead of `Escape` in readline or the terminal in general without any extra configuration.

You can also bind any of `Ctrl-@`, `Ctrl-[A-Z]`, `Ctrl-[`, `Ctrl-\`, `Ctrl-]`, `Ctrl-^` and `Ctrl-_` (provided they're not a terminal special character like `Ctrl-D` => `eof` or `Ctrl-\` => `quit`) with eg:

```
bind '"\C-@": "\e"'
```

On some terminals, `Ctrl-@` is also generated by the `` Ctrl-`‎ `` combo, and `Ctrl-_` by the `Ctrl-/` combo.

Also, the `Alt-key` combinations are usually mapped to `Esc-key` in most terminals (subject to terminal emulator settings), so you can bind for instance `Alt-C` instead of `Ctrl-C` to `Escape` with:

```
bind '"\ec":"\e"'
```

---

For the `Ctrl-C` part, `Ctrl-C` is handled as a special key (`intr`) by the tty driver before even reaching bash or readline, since readline doesn't turn off the `ISIG` tty setting when entering the line editor. You can of course, always do eg.

```
stty intr ^]; bind '"\C-C":"\e"'
```

and retrain you to use `Ctrl-]` instead of `Ctrl-C` when you want to interrupt a job, but that's quite obviously a very bad idea.

Comment: Unfortunately i am not using US layout, so the `]` is very cumbersome.

Comment: What would be the syntax for using some arbitrary key for `$something`?

Comment: @oarfish The `Ctrl-]` was obviously just an example. Readline can only rebind character (sequences) which are available in the terminal (no `CapsLock`, etc). If you want to rebind keys at system or terminal emulator level, then please ask another Q and mention all the needed details (which terminal are you using, etc).